# Copy&Replace only files with different content

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, command-line, merge

I copy files from folder A to folder B including subfolder. If files already exists in folder B I want to replace them only when content is different. I dont want to overwrite timestamps on files with the same content.

I can do it easily using total commander or simmilar tool, but i would like to be able to do it only using command line, visual studio command prompt or powershell. tf diff command is an option

Comment: What have you tried so far? If this were my problem to solve then I think I would just use file hashes to decide whether to copy or not.

Comment: this gives me quite good comparison: `tf folderdiff A B /recursive /filter:*.xml` but the result includes also some folder, not only files. However I'm not very good at piping and grepping those command line commands

Comment: You can use robocopy for this sort of thing.

Comment: Good call. The /XC flag should limit the copy to changed files.

Answer (score 0):

Use Robocopy.  It works well called from powershell, or just the commandline.

```
PS M:\> robocopy

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Started : Wed Apr 22 11:38:09 2015

    Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR

          source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).  
     destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).  
            /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.  

    For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /?

****  /MIR can DELETE files as well as copy them !
```

Comment: Robocopy compares files based on timestamp. If I have the same file in folders A and B, but different timestamp, robocopy overwrites the file in folder B and I want to avoid this

Comment: Recommend using total commander (whatever that is) then, since you're using a very subjective set of criteria to determine which file is current.
To automate this using any method will require that you have a logical way of making this decision based on properties of the file.

Comment: I want to copy folder A to B and then check in only differences to TFS. I can't overwrite all files, because tfs recognize them as changed, even they are not. I just dont want to check in thousends of unchaned files to tfs.

Comment: Robocopy /? shows the full help for Robocopy.

I think you're looking for `Robocopy source destination /MIR /XO` which will copy source including structure and files within it, but it will skip unchanged files.  Be warned it will remove destination files which are removed from source.

Comment: XO does not skip unchanged files

Comment: md a;
dir > a\file1.txt;
robocopy a b /MIR /XO;
dir > a\file2.txt;
robocopy a b /MIR /XO; 
robocopy a b /MIR /XO; # replace the ';' with returns, you will see that it does, in fact, skip unchanged files.  Second robocopy will only copy the one new file (file2.txt) and third robocopy will copy zero files.  Run the commands from a safe location, like c:\temp or something.

Comment: XO skips older files. I dont care whether its older or newer. I don't know how to say it more clearly

Comment: If it is unchanged, then it is 'older' to robocopy and it will be skipped.  I don't know how to say it more clearly either.  Good luck.